# PHP: can't read checkbox's | $_GET is empty. Why?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, get

I just want to read which checkboxes are checked, but I get always the message that the index is undefined, and in $_GET is nothing.

So maybe you can tell me why, and how I can fix it. My php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
      <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="checkbox.php">
<input type="hidden" name="sent" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="hello" checked>hello<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="cu"checked>cu<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test"checked>test<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test2"checked>test2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="bond"checked>bond<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump($_GET);
print_r($_GET["sent"]);
     $sent = $_GET['sent'];                     
     $name = $_GET['name']; 

     if ($sent == 'yes') {
             $name_test = implode(', ',$name);

            print_r($name_test);
     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If i run the script ind the windows cmd, using xampp i get the following respons:

```
PS C:\xampp\php> php-cgi G:\1\checkbox.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
      <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="checkbox.php">
<input type="hidden" name="sent" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="hello" checked>hello<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="cu"checked>cu<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test"checked>test<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test2"checked>test2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="bond"checked>bond<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

array(1) {
["G:\1\checkbox_php"]=>
string(0) ""
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: sent in <b>G:\1\checkbox.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br   />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: sent in <b>G:\1\checkbox.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>G:\1\checkbox.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand, why there is nothing in the $_GET variable. This code was an example. I found it on a german tutorialsite.

http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/php/checkboxen/

I test it by copy the code and just change the names for you.

Comment: Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for this.

Comment: Yeah i now that, but this isn't my question. I want the array where i can see which box's are checked. But i don't get it, why?

Comment: do you see the values in the url parameters ?

Comment: add method="get" to your form and see hear http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Comment: You probably want to submit the form first for $_GET to be populated

Comment: How did u submit the form? or u think making checked will automatically submit the form and put variable in url

Comment: the problem is, i just can test it by using the windows cmd. But in the code all box's are checked. So it must be possible, to get it, or not?

Comment: The first code block is the content of `checkbox.php` or is a different script?

Comment: Put this `if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['sent'])){` below `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then a `}` brace after `print_r($name_test);` and use `<form action="">` if in same file which seems to be the case.

Comment: @SnowN it is not possible read more http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @SnowN You need to submit the form first.. You cannot just execute the .php file on cmd and expect it to work

Comment: the script called checkbox.php

Comment: k, if i submit in in chrome i get the following: file:///C:/xampp/php/checkbox.php?sent=yes&name%5B%5D=bond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is because in the first  time you load your script the `$_GET` is empty, until you submit your form `$_GET['sent']` and `$_GET['name']` will have assigned values I made this fix and it works :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
      <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="checkbox.php">
<input type="hidden" name="sent" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="hello" checked>hello<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="cu"checked>cu<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test"checked>test<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="test2"checked>test2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="bond"checked>bond<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (array_key_exists('sent', $_GET) || array_key_exists('name', $_GET))
{
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump($_GET);
print_r($_GET["sent"]);
     $sent = $_GET['sent'];                     
     $name = $_GET['name']; 

     if ($sent == 'yes') {
             $name_test = implode(', ',$name);

            print_r($name_test);
     }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not really about a fix for the script. It's not working becasue the OP is executing this in a shell instead of a webserver

Comment: In that case you can try this: `php -e checkbox.php name[]=hello&name[]=cu&name[]=test&sent=yes`

Comment: Not sure about windows. But on linux this will not work

Answer (score 0):

**Guess this is the output you want.**

Do your php like this

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_GET["sent"]))
{

     $sent = $_GET['sent'];                      

     if ($sent == 'yes') {
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
echo "<h2> These boxes were checked</h2>";
      foreach($_GET['name'] as $name)
{
echo $name . "<br />";
}
}
else
 echo "nothing was checked";

     }
}
?>
```

When you click on the submit it will give the result you want.